# -[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "DeviceConfigViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitableview

I am facing the crash in custom class derived from UITableViewController. I have gone through the various post but didn't get the solution. I do not have any UITableView outlet component. Then how do I link with one? I want to upload my app to store. but it said you need launch image supporting iPhone 5. so I added that image.Then I found that I need to upgrade my   Xcode for iOS 6.0. I did that too. Then it says Xcode 4.6.2 requires the higher version of OS.  So,I did that too. And again come to point to upload procedure. But before that I did some verification. and found out the the view controller which is derived from UITableViewController is crashing. and showing the above error.

Any direction will be great. Thanks.

Comment: without code is going to be really hard for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the view outlet of your table view controller with an UITableView.